# How to fix my if statement in my python code?

Tags: python, algorithm, file, if-statement, debugging

I am trying to make a program that will calculate your popularity and based on that, use an algorithm to cycle through a friend list and open txt files based on that, then calculate their popularity, and if it is in a radius of 10 popularity points, they are put as compatible. However, my code is not working and my if statement keeps returning true no matter what. However, when printing the popularities, it says some are in my range, and some aren't. Why is my code failing?

```
def popularity(G, So, Sm, Sp):
    g = float(G) * 0.3
    so = float(So) * 0.4
    sm = float(Sm) * 0.1
    sp = float(Sp) * 0.2
    return g + so + sm + sp

gfactor = input("What is your G-Factor? ")
social = input("What is your Social Quotient? ")
smartness = input("What is your smartness level? ")
sports = input("What is your sports skill? ")

poplr = popularity(gfactor, social, smartness, sports)
print(str(math.ceil(poplr * float(10))) + "%")
print("Finding friends... ")

for i in friends:
    fs = open(i + ".txt")
    json_str = fs.read(37)
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    friend_poplr = popularity(data["g"], data["So"], data["Sm"], data["Sp"]) * float(10)
    if friend_poplr > float(poplr) - float(10):
        if friend_poplr < float(poplr) + float(10):
            print("# " + i + " is a compatible friend #")
        else:
            print("# " + i + " is not a compatible friend #")
    else:
            print("# " + i + " is not a compatible friend #")
```

Yes, I have imported math and json, and also have a list of friends, but I am censoring their names. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: why do you multiply friends' popularity by 10?

Comment: Putting it as percentage

Comment: Please mark this and previous questions you have asked as answered if you find any of the answers as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that you multiply `friend_polr` by 10 and you dont do the same for `poplr`.  All you need to do is multiply poplr by 10 to make them both even.  In my example below i made some other minor improvements to your code

```
def popularity(G, So, Sm, Sp):
    g = float(G) * 0.3
    so = float(So) * 0.4
    sm = float(Sm) * 0.1
    sp = float(Sp) * 0.2
    return g + so + sm + sp

gfactor = input("What is your G-Factor? ")
social = input("What is your Social Quotient? ")
smartness = input("What is your smartness level? ")
sports = input("What is your sports skill? ")

poplr = popularity(gfactor, social, smartness, sports) * 10

print(str(math.ceil(poplr)) + "%")
print("Finding friends... ")

for i in friends:
    fs = open(i + ".txt")
    json_str = fs.read(37)
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    fs.close()                   # remember to close the file
    friend_poplr = popularity(data["g"], data["So"], data["Sm"], data["Sp"]) * 10
    if friend_poplr > poplr - 10:
        if friend_poplr < poplr + 10:
            print("# " + i + " is a compatible friend #")
            continue
    print("# " + i + " is not a compatible friend #")
```